# Count #records per minute with a MySQL timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains a timestamp column, declaring the time the record was created. Is there a way I can count the records in the table, and "slice" them in 1-min intervals to count how many records are created each minute?

Comment: I would that in the application logic

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou why? That’s a task databases are very good at! On the front end would be like reinventing the wheel imho

Comment: sometime I am more comfortable with app logic...the advantage of a query is of course performance....but if the app is small...performance gains are not so big....performance gains become noticeable usually on edge cases

Comment: Do some arithmetic:  Either via div and modulo 60 or `LEFT(datetime, 15)`

Answer (score 2):

With nothing to go on I would suggest

```
select column, minute(timestampColumn), count(*) as `Count`
from table
group by column, minute(timestampColumn)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful however it groups by minute. So if the records span multiple hours, they will get added together under the same minute number.

Comment: with 35k rep you really should know you need to provide a certain amount of detail and clarity in a question; just group by `hour` as well - but again, a guess without a clear example of expected results!

Comment: That did it, thanks!